# How to embed jar file in Windows batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

I'd like to do something similar to https://coderwall.com/p/ssuaxa/how-to-make-a-jar-file-linux-executable in Windows.

Context: I'm writing a `protoc` add-on which requires one and only one executable file being used.

I've created a `stub.bat` file with the following contents:

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java" -jar %~dp0%0 %*
```

and followed similar instructions as what's described for Unix, but upon running the generated batch file, I'm seeing:

```
Hello, World
'□' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The "Hello, World" is an indication that what I'm doing is actually working. But how can the garbage at the end be eliminated?

Comment: The Windows command line `CMD.EXE` is not like any of the Linux/Unix shells, and Windows doesn't handle executability like Unix/Linux. Why would you think it does? You need to look into the [`FTYPE`](https://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html) and [`ASSOC`](https://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html) commands in Windows, and not try to bind the executable to the batch file, which will not work.

Comment: I'm not thinking that they work the same. I asked how the garbage can be eliminated.

Also, that `Hello, World` is an indication that the binding actually worked.

Comment: I've also added context to the question.

Comment: The reason you're getting that garbage is the same reason your binding won't work - CMD is trying to read past the end of the batch commands, into the java bytecode. Which it then tries to execute as though it's a batch command or the name of a .EXE file.

Comment: I understand that. The question is _how_ it can be eliminated, not why it's happening. For example, `exit` can be called but that would exit the entire shell. Is there a batch command that simply means "end execution without exiting"?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html indicates using `exit /b` should do what I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End `stub.bat` with:

```
exit /b
```

From https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html:

```
Syntax
      EXIT [/B] [exitCode]

Key
    /B        When used in a batch script, this option will exit 
              only the script (or subroutine) but not CMD.EXE

   exitCode   Sets the %ERRORLEVEL% to a numeric number.
              If quitting CMD.EXE, set the process exit code no.
```